# Solr Ngram Synonyms Dismax

Tags: solr, lucene

I have ngram-indexed 2 fields (columns in the database) and the third one is my full text field. Now my default text field is the full text field and while querying I use dismax handler and specify in it both the ngrammed field with certain boost values and also full text field with a certain boost value.

Problem for me if I dont use dismax and just search full text field(i.e. default field specified in schema) synonyms work correctly i.e. ca returns all results where california is there whereas if i use dismax ca is also searched in the ngrammed fields and return partial matches of the word ca and does not go at all in the synonym part.

I want to use synonyms in every case so how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you already correctly configured the "SynonymFilterFactory" filter in your ngram field's query analyzer.

If still doesn't work, the Solr admin's analysis interface can give more details of the tokenize/filter procedures, through which can check if the Synonym part already works as expected.

Comment: +1 Yinan, great help. Thanks a lot. Hmmm how I missed that pretty simple thing.